# concatenating string variables to obtain value

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

How would I concatenate these two string variables in Django templates? At the moment question.correct_answer is the position the correct answer should be (so if there were 4 potential answers and the first answer was correct, `question.correct_answer` would return 1 instead of the value the answer holds.

I have tried the below code, but it shows a string of 'question.answer_1'

```py
                <h5 class="homework_desc"> {{ question.answer_4 }}</h5>
                <br>
                <h4 class="homework_correct hidden" id="{{question.id}}">
                    {{'question.answer_'|add:question.correct_answer}}
                </h4>
```

Comment: Please don't. Move the logic to the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't. Django template language deliberately restricts subscripting, method calls, etc. to prevent people from writing business logic in the template.

You can implement this in the `Question` model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    answer_1 = …
    answer_2 = …
    answer_3 = …
    answer_4 = …
    correct_answer = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def correct_answer_value(self):
        return (
            self.answer_1
          , self.answer_2
          , self.answer_3
          , self.answer_4
          )[self.correct_answer-1]
```

then in the template you can render this with:

```
<h4 class="homework_correct hidden" id="{{question.id}}">
    {{ question.correct_answer_value }}
</h4>
```